# Changing language - LaTeX classic thesis template

Tags: templates, languages

I'm trying to change language in the classic thesis template from american to italian, but it does not work. In particular in the file "ClassicThesis" there is the command (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis?lang=en ):

```
\selectlanguage{american}
```

if I use:

```
\selectlanguage{italian}
```

or

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

the compiler shows an error. I changed also the command:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{italian}{babel}
```

in the file "classicthesis-config".

I'm using Texmaker to open latex files.

---

EDIT: the error is:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown language `ngerman'. Either you have
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: Hello @PhilipPirris, it is difficult to post the errors because they are long and thus are difficult to read. Do you think that I have to post it?

Comment: Yes, and they are not long, but very nicely formatted in a log file of the run. Alternatively you could make a minimal compilable example showing the issue.

Comment: Post at least a few lines before and after the relevant error message. Post it as code. The original package is for American and German. What happens when you replace all mentions of German with Italian. Make sure you have all necessary Italian language packages installed, i.e. that other Italian docs work for you.

Comment: You need to pass to babel all language options you'll be using. I suppose you still have `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` somewhere in the files (probably Abstract.tex) but are not listing ngerman in `\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman,italian,american}{babel}`

Comment: Thank you so much for your very good answer @PhilipPirrip. Now it seems to work.

Comment: @Gennaro I'm glad to hear that. Don't forget to send a postcard! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one's working with the original template, all language options that will be used in thesis files by `\selectlanguage{italian}` & co. should be added to `\PassOptionsToPackage{italian,ngerman,american}{babel}` in `classicthesis-config.tex`. The last language listed (here: american) is the *main* language of the thesis.